# combining conditions in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I am trying to find all posts made by a user or his frnds...

So far i have this

```
Activity.any_of({"user_id" => 1}, {"for_id" => 1}, {"comments.user_id" => 1})
```

now, how do i add to these the condition that user_id can be by anyone who is a frnd of user... will doing this work?

```
Activity.any_of({"user_id" => 1}, {"for_id" => 1}, {"comments.user_id" => 1}).any_in("user_in" => [1,2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it in rails but the query you're looking for is either :

```
db.posts.find({$or:[{user_id:1}, {user_id:{$in:[friend_id1, friend_id2,.. friend_idn]}}]})
```

Or a bit easier, combine your user id and your friend user ids into one list and do

```
db.posts.find({user_id:{$in:[user_id, friend_id1, friend_id2,.. friend_idn]}})
```